# Unobserve IntersectionObserver in React.useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, observable

I am trying to get the `top` and `bottom` measurements from multiple elements by using `IntersectionObserver`. However, once I have the measurements, how can I `unobserve` the elements.

The problem is that each element is `position: sticky` and when scrolling additional values are added to the `array` and I only want the measurements from the initial render.

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const measurement = {
        top: entry.boundingClientRect.top,
        bottom: entry.boundingClientRect.bottom,
      };
      console.log(measurement);
    });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll(`section#dark`)
    sections.forEach((section) => observer.observe(section));
    return () => {
      // observer.disconnect(); removed in Stackoverflow edit
      sections.forEach(section => observer.observe(section)); // Added in Stackoverflow edit
    };
  }, []);
```

I have tried using `observer.unobserve()` but cannot figure out what value it requires as it returns an error of `Argument of type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.`

EDIT: I figured out how to use `oberver.unobserve` with `sections.forEach(section => observer.unobserve(section));` but it still adds more records when scrolling.

Full example can be seen here [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eqjja2?file=src%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the observer instance to `useEffect` block because every time your component is updated a new `IntersectionObserver`  instance is created:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const measurement = {
        top: entry.boundingClientRect.top,
        bottom: entry.boundingClientRect.bottom,
      };
      console.log(measurement);
      observer.unobserve(entry.target); //<-- call unobserve here
      });
    });
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(`section#dark`)
  sections.forEach((section) => observer.observe(section));
  return () => {
     observer.disconnect();
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it is still adding the values on scrolling. I will add an update to the question to show this.

Comment: Can you create a workin example here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react?file=src%2FApp.js to reproduce your problem

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eqjja2?file=src%2FApp.js find it here. Thank you.

Comment: @Darren did you tried observer.unobserve(entry.target)?

Comment: I did but received `Property 'target' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: Yes but that shouldn't make much difference, should it?

Comment: I got unobserve to work using `      sections.forEach(section => observer.unobserve(section));` but it is still creating more records.

Comment: What do you mean with creating more records? where are these records added?

Comment: The `measurement` objects with the `top` and `bottom` value. They are shown in the console when scrolling down and caused by the position of the sticky sections moving up.

Comment: If you want to get the values of the first render, you should call unobserved  in Interception observer callback function, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2vkdqt?file=src%2Fhook.js, the console log will display only once per entry

Comment: That is correct. Thank you. Did you want to update your answer so I can accept.